# C++ Singly Linked List - Using a sentinel

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list, deque, sentinel

I'd like to use a sentinel in my linked list implementation to simplify some of the functions.

However the `Deque() = default;` constructor is confusing me.

How does it know that It has to set head = tail followed by a sentinel 
for the initial construction of a Deque linked list with no elements when I don't/can't define it to do so?

This is just homework for one of my classes that I'm trying to work through and understand. We weren't asked to use sentinels but I'd like to.

Deque.cpp

```
//2 example functions using sentinels
#include "Deque.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

bool Deque::empty() const
{
    if ((head->next == tail) && (tail->next == sentinel))
        {return true;}
    return false;
}


int Deque::size() const
{
    int size_val = 0;
    const Node* p = head.get();

    while ( p != sentinel)
        {
        size_val++;
        p = p->next.get();
        }
    return size_val;
}
```

Deque.h

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <memory>

class Deque{
    public:
        Deque() = default;
        Deque(const Deque&);
        ~Deque(); // const space
        Deque& operator=(const Deque&);

        bool empty() const;
        int size() const;

    private:
    friend Node;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> sentinel;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> head ;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> tail ;
};
```

Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Node {
public:
    Node(const Node& n) : val{n.val}, next{}
    {
    }
    Node(int v, std::unique_ptr<Node> n) : val{v}, next{move(n)}
    {
    }
    Node(int v) : val{v}
    {
    }

private:
    int val = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next = nullptr;

    friend class Deque;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Node&);
};

#endif
```

Comment: My guess is here sentinel means `NULL`, because after tail you will have nothing to get or traversed.

Comment: If the constructor is confusing you, why did you write it like that?

Comment: fix this: if ((head->next = tail) && (tail->next = sentinel)). change to ==

Comment: @molbdnilo its homework - I can't change that.